# Folium Choropleth Highlight map elements is not working

Tags: python, geojson, folium, choropleth

This is my first question so hopefully, I'm asking it in a way that makes sense. If not, please correct me.

I want to use the highlight parameter in `folium.Choropleth` to achieve this sort of behaviour on mouse hover:

[image: Choropleth]

but it's not working.

I noticed one strange thing:
I also have `folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip` in my code and if I disable it, highlighting works. But when it's enabled, highlighting does not work. When `folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip` is enabled, the code compiles without errors but it's not highlighting countries as it should. All other functionalities work as expected.

```
folium.Choropleth(
geo_data=df1,
name="choropleth",
data=df3,
columns=["Country", "Estimate_UN"],
key_on="feature.properties.name",
fill_color="YlGnBu",
fill_opacity=0.8,
line_opacity=0.5,
legend_name="GDP Per Capita (in EUR)",
bins=bins,
highlight=True
).add_to(my_map)
```

Here's my full code:

```
import folium
import pandas
import geopandas

pandas.set_option('display.max_columns',25)
pandas.set_option('display.width',2000)
pandas.set_option('display.max_rows',300)

url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_(nominal)_per_capita'
tables1 = pandas.read_html(url, match='Country/Territory')
df1 = tables1[0]  # changes data from List to DataFrame

# makes it single index
df1.columns = ['Country', 'Region', 'Estimate_IMF', 'Year1', 'Estimate_UN', 'Year2', 'Estimate_WB', 'Year3']
# makes it two columns only (Country, Estimate_UN)
df1 = df1.drop(columns=['Region', 'Year1', 'Year2', 'Year3', 'Estimate_IMF', 'Estimate_WB'])

df1['Country'] = df1['Country'].map(lambda x: x.rstrip('*'))
df1['Country'] = df1['Country'].map(lambda x: x.strip())
df1['Country'] = df1['Country'].str.replace('United States', 'United States of America')
df1['Country'] = df1['Country'].str.replace('DR Congo', 'Dem. Rep. Congo')
df1['Country'] = df1['Country'].str.replace('Central African Republic', 'Central African Rep.')
df1['Country'] = df1['Country'].str.replace('South Sudan', 'S. Sudan')
df1['Country'] = df1['Country'].str.replace('Czech Republic', 'Czechia')
df1['Country'] = df1['Country'].str.replace('Bosnia and Herzegovina', 'Bosnia and Herz.')
df1['Country'] = df1['Country'].str.replace('Ivory Coast', """Côte d'Ivoire""")
df1['Country'] = df1['Country'].str.replace('Dominican Republic', 'Dominican Rep.')
df1['Country'] = df1['Country'].str.replace('Eswatini', 'eSwatini')
df1['Country'] = df1['Country'].str.replace('Equatorial Guinea', 'Eq. Guinea')
df1.drop(df1[df1['Estimate_UN'] == '—'].index, inplace = True)
df1['Estimate_UN'] = df1['Estimate_UN'].apply(lambda g:int(str(g)))

### --- Change 'GDP Per Capita' values in GeoJsonToolTip from format of 12345.0 (USD) to €11,604 --- ###

df2 = df1.copy()
df2['Estimate_UN'] = df2['Estimate_UN'].apply(lambda g:g*0.94) # Convert USD to EUR

df3 = df2.copy()

df2['Estimate_UN'] = df2['Estimate_UN'].apply(lambda g:str(int(g)))
df2['Estimate_UN'] = '€' + df2['Estimate_UN'].astype(str)

length = (df2['Estimate_UN'].str.len())

df2.loc[length == 7, 'Estimate_UN'] = df2[['Estimate_UN']].astype(str).replace(r"(\d{3})(\d+)", r"\1,\2", regex=True)
df2.loc[length == 6, 'Estimate_UN'] = df2[['Estimate_UN']].astype(str).replace(r"(\d{2})(\d+)", r"\1,\2", regex=True)
df2.loc[length == 5, 'Estimate_UN'] = df2[['Estimate_UN']].astype(str).replace(r"(\d{1})(\d+)", r"\1,\2", regex=True)

### --- Create map --- ###

world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
df1 = world.merge(df1, how='left', left_on=['name'], right_on=['Country'])
df1 = df1.dropna(subset=['Estimate_UN'])

df2 = world.merge(df2, how='left', left_on=['name'], right_on=['Country'])
df2 = df2.dropna(subset=['Estimate_UN'])

df3 = world.merge(df3, how='left', left_on=['name'], right_on=['Country'])
df3 = df3.dropna(subset=['Estimate_UN'])

my_map = folium.Map(location=(39.22753573470106, -3.650093262568073),
    zoom_start=2, 
    tiles = 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', 
    attr = 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye,Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community',
    min_zoom=2, 
    min_lot=-179, 
    max_lot=179, 
    min_lat=-65, 
    max_lat=179, 
    max_bounds=True)

### --- Add tooltip --- ###

gdp = folium.FeatureGroup(name="GDP")

gdp.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=df2, tooltip = folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
    fields=['Country','Estimate_UN'], 
    aliases=['Country:','GDP Per Capita:'],
    style=("background-color: white; color: #333333; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; padding: 10px;"),
    localize = True),
    style_function= lambda y:{
    'stroke':'false',
    'opacity':'0',
    }))

### --- Color countries --- ###

bins = [100,1000,5000,10000,20000,35000,50000,112000]

folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=df1,
    name="choropleth",
    data=df3,
    columns=["Country", "Estimate_UN"],
    key_on="feature.properties.name",
    fill_color="YlGnBu",
    fill_opacity=0.8,
    line_opacity=0.5,
    legend_name="GDP Per Capita (in EUR)",
    bins=bins,
    highlight=True
    ).add_to(my_map)

my_map.add_child(gdp)
my_map.save('index.html')
```

I'm looking forward to your suggestions on why `GeoJsonTooltip` is stopping the highlight parameter from working!

Comment: The first thing I would like to check is that if the user data is df1, it needs to be df1 in the data designation, which is currently df3. Is the geodata a geojson file or a geopandas? If so, are 'country' and 'name' related? I haven't tried your code because you don't provide any geodata, but you don't provide any tooltip code.

Comment: @r-beginners Thank you for your input. There is a full code below where you can see tooltip code line 74 - 84. Geodata is taken from the geopandas directly. The code should run for you with no external files. Regarding the data it is geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame type. Country and name is merged together and has same values.

And now I think that's what may be causing problem. Because tooltip is folium.GeoJson. But still, when hovering over the mouse it identifies each country correctly and displays right info, just doesn't highlight it

Comment: I am very sorry. I made my comment based on the displayed part only. I checked all codes. Simply put, I understand that `folium.Choropleth()` has a highlight function but no tooltip or popup function, so it can be achieved using `folium.Geojson()`.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that `folium.Choropleth()` has a highlighting feature, but no popup or tooltip feature. If you want to use the tooltip and popup functions, use `folium.Geojson()`. I will respond with a df3 of the data you presented.

- I have implemented my own color map for color coding. The index of
  the color map is modified according to the number of colors. See this
  for [more information](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/GeoJSON_and_choropleth.ipynb) about our own colormaps.
- The tooltip is introduced as you set it up. We have also added a
  pop-up feature. You can add supplementary information. If you don't
  need it, please delete it.
- The color fill is specified by the style function, which gets the
  color name from the estimated value for the previously specified
  colormap function. At the same time, a highlight function is added to
  change the transparency of the map drawing. The basic code can be found [here](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/GeoJsonPopupAndTooltip.ipynb).

```
import folium
from folium.features import GeoJsonPopup, GeoJsonTooltip
import branca

bins = [5000,25000,45000,65000,112000]

my_map = folium.Map(location=(39.22753573470106, -3.650093262568073),
    zoom_start=2, 
    tiles = 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', 
    attr = 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye,Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community',
    min_zoom=2, 
    min_lot=-179, 
    max_lot=179, 
    min_lat=-65, 
    max_lat=179, 
    max_bounds=True)

colormap = branca.colormap.LinearColormap(
    vmin=df3['Estimate_UN'].quantile(0.0),
    vmax=df3['Estimate_UN'].quantile(1),
    colors=["red", "orange", "lightblue", "green", "darkgreen"],
    caption="Original Colormap",
    index=bins
)

tooltip = folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
    fields=['Country','Estimate_UN'],
    aliases=['Country:','GDP Per Capita:'],
    style=("background-color: white; color: #333333; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; padding: 10px;"),
    localize=True)

popup = GeoJsonPopup(
    fields=['Country','Estimate_UN'],
    aliases=['Country:','GDP Per Capita:'],
    localize=True,
    labels=True,
    style="background-color: yellow;",
)

folium.GeoJson(data=df3,
               tooltip=tooltip,
               popup=popup,
               style_function= lambda y:{
                   "fillColor": colormap(y["properties"]["Estimate_UN"]),
                   'stroke':'false',
                   'opacity': 0.4
               },
               highlight_function=lambda x: {'fillOpacity': 0.8},
              ).add_to(my_map)

colormap.add_to(my_map)
# my_map.save('index.html')
my_map
```

[image]